# Names of the columns we're searching for missing values

Tags: median

Searching for missing values ?

```
columns = ['median', 'p25th', 'p75th']

# Look at the dtypes of the columns
print(____)

# Find how missing values are represented (Search for missing values in the median, p25th, and p75th columns.)
print(recent_grads["median"].____)

# Replace missing values with NaN,using numpy's np.nan.
for column in ___:
    recent_grads.loc[____ == '____', column] = ____?
```

Comment: for hint we can use 
Try selecting the three columns in columns and then looking at the .dtypes attribute of the resulting DataFrame.
Call the .unique() method on the median column.
Use a boolean expression to filter the columns so that you only have rows with a value of UN.
numpy has an np.nan object that you can use to replace the values.

Comment: For more instruction you can use:
Look at the dtypes of the columns in columns to make sure that the data is numeric.
It looks like a string is being used to encode missing values. Use the .unique() method to figure out what the string is.
Search for missing values in the median, p25th, and p75th columns.
Replace the found missing values with a NaN value, using numpy's np.nan.

Comment: for column in columns:
    recent_grads.loc[column == 'UN', column] = np.nan
#getting error
cannot use single boolean to index into set item

Comment: #for column in columns:
    recent_grads.loc[column == 'UN', column] = np.nan(Getting error)
    #recent_grads[columns] = recent_grads[columns].replace({'UN':np.nan}) (this code is working fine )

Answer (score 3):

Names of the columns we're searching for missing values

```
columns = ['median', 'p25th', 'p75th']
```

Take a look at the dtypes

```
print(recent_grads[columns].dtypes)
```

Find how missing values are represented

```
print(recent_grads["median"].unique())
```

Replace missing values with NaN

```
for column in columns:
    recent_grads.loc[recent_grads[column] == 'UN', column] = np.nan
```

Answer (score 1):

right answer is--

```
for column in columns:
  recent_grads.loc[recent_grads[column] == 'UN', column] = np.nan
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# Print .dtypes
print(recent_grads.dtypes)

# Output summary statistics
print(recent_grads.describe())

# Exclude data of type object
print(recent_grads.describe(exclude=["object"]))
```